# Python subprocess call returns "command not found", Terminal executes correctly

Tags: python, shell, terminal, subprocess

I am trying to run gphoto2 from python but, with no succes. It just returns command not found.
gphoto is installed correctly, as in, the commands work fine in Terminal.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['gphoto2'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, executable='/bin/bash')

for line in p.stdout.readlines():
    print line
p.wait()

/bin/bash: gphoto2: command not found
```

I know that there is something funny about the osx Terminal (app) but, my knowledge on osx is meager.

Any thoughts on this one?

EDIT

changed some of my code, other errors appear

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['gphoto2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in p.stdout:
    print line


    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

EDIT

using full path '/opt/local/bin/gphoto2'

but if someone care to explain which shell to use or how to log in and be able to have the same functionality..?

Comment: Why don’t you use `subprocess.check_output()` or output the whole thing at a time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using `shell = True`, the first argument to `subprocess.Popen` should be a string, not a list:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('gphoto2', shell=True, ...)
```

However, using `shell = True` should be avoided if possible since it can be a [security risk](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) (see the Warning).

So instead use

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['gphoto2'], ...)
```

(When `shell = False`, or if the `shell` parameter is omitted, the first argument should be a list.)

Comment: thanks, refactored my code correctly know. Although it brought me no further. I have edited my post

Comment: What happens if you use the full path to `gphoto2`?

Comment: Try the command `which gphoto2` at the terminal to find the full path.

Comment: I would avoid adding full path to the code... it is better to add to `os.environ['PATH']` as different runtime env might have different path