# Executing bash commands from flask application

Tags: python, bash, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Application Details: Ubuntu 16.04 + flask + nginx + uwsgi

I am trying to execute a bash command from flask application.

```py
@app.route('/hello', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def hello():
    os.system('mkdir my_directory')
    return "Hello"
```

The above code run successfully but doesn't create any directory. Also it creates directory on my local which doesn't have any nginx level setup.

I also tried following ways:

1. subprocess.call(['mkdir', 'my_directory']) # Throws Internal server error
2. subprocess.call(['mkdir', 'my_directory'],shell=True) # No error but directory not created
3. subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', 'my_directory']) # Throws Internal server error
4. subprocess.Popen(['mkdir', 'my_directory'],shell=True) # No error but directory not created

Do I need any nginx level configuration changes.

Comment: Did you try `import os  os.makedirs(my_directory)` ?

Comment: it will create my_directory inside whatever directory your app is running on, try giving it an absolute path instead of a directory name. e.g. mkdir /home/you/output_dirs/my_directory

Comment: The code attempts to create the directory in the working directory. Try to see the working directory by os.getcwd(). May the application doesn't have r/w access to that folder. 

Also, check the return code for subprocess.call.

Comment: @Pradeepb os.makedirs is working. But any shell command is not working.

Comment: @VivekAkupatni subprocess.call is returning 127. And I am creating directory in the current working directory which I think all r/w access. Because I am able to create directory using `os.makedirs` from the same point of execution.

Comment: The ones which give "Internal server error" are correct. The problem is *probably* that you don't have permission to create a directory in that location. (Well, except you should use `check_call()` instead of `call()` and definitely not bare `Popen()` here. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Comment: When I am executing `subprocess.Popen("mkdir my_directory",shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')` then in my syslog, I am getting `/bin/bash: mkdir: command not found`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the point. I followed [Python subprocess call returns “command not found”, Terminal executes correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9506481/2248566)
.

What I was missing was absolute path of `mkdir`. When I executed `subprocess.call(["/bin/mkdir", "my_directory"])`, it makes the directory successfully.

The above link contains complete details.

Also I would be thankful if anyone will describe the reason that why I need to specify absolute path for `mkdir`.

Thanks to all. :)

Comment: also i have the same problem, i think it is from uwsgi, because when i run the flask development server i don't use the full path, i use just "mkdir".